# WCF web service can not find endpoint element that references the default contract

Tags: c#, wcf, service, web

I have a server with two services:

1. `ContactService` with `IContactService` and
2. `SessionService` with `ISessionService`

I have an error when I execute :

> "Impossible de trouver un élément de point de terminaison par défaut qui fait référence au contrat 
>   'SessionServiceReference.ISessionService' dans la section de configuration du client ServiceModel. 
>   Ceci peut être dû au fait que le fichier de configuration de votre application est introuvable ou 
>   que l'élément de point de terminaison correspondant à ce contrat est introuvable dans l'élément client."

My web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="InstantMessagingBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00">
          <textMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="200000" maxArrayLength="200000" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport keepAliveEnabled="false" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000" authenticationScheme="Ntlm"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="InstantMessagingBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Isima.InstantMessaging.WcfService.ContactService" behaviorConfiguration="InstantMessagingBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="InstantMessagingBinding"
          contract="Isima.InstantMessaging.WcfService.IContactService" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
      <service name="Isima.InstantMessaging.WcfService.SessionService" behaviorConfiguration="InstantMessagingBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="InstantMessagingBinding"
          contract="Isima.InstantMessaging.WcfService.ISessionService" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

and app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="CustomBinding_IContactService">
          <textMessageEncoding />
          <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Ntlm" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="CustomBinding_ISessionService">
          <textMessageEncoding />
          <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Ntlm" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:2984/ContactService.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IContactService"
        contract="ContactServiceReference.IContactService" name="CustomBinding_IContactService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:2984/SessionService.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_ISessionService"
        contract="SessionServiceReference.ISessionService" name="CustomBinding_ISessionService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Why this error ?

Comment: it looks like as if you have hosting problems. Add mex point and test your service by adress. What type of hosting do you use?

Comment: I assume you have a svc file in your project, and you are hosting on port 80. In which case .net is complaining that your svc is saying there should be an endpoint there. But your config does not configure for it...